# Guessing random number game python

Tags: python, random

My program is supposed to ask the user to guess a number between 0 and 100 however I can't seem to get the output right. At the moment if the the User number is greater than the random number, it prints out an infinite amount of "Your number is too high." Also if the first UserGuess is low, then all the following numbers will have the same prompt: ("Your number is too low") despite them being actually bigger than the random number. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
from random import randint

def main():


    guessesTaken = 0

    randomNumber = randint(0,100)
    #print(randomNumber)
    giveUp = -1
    UserGuess = int(input("Take a guess" + "(The random number is: " + str(randomNumber) + "): "))

    while UserGuess != randomNumber:

        guessesTaken += 1

        if UserGuess < randomNumber:
            UserGuess = int(input("Your guess is too high.Try again: "))

        elif UserGuess > randomNumber:
            UserGuess = int(input("Your guess is too high.Try again: "))

        elif UserGuess == randomNumber or UserGuess == giveUp:
            break

    if UserGuess  == randomNumber:
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
        print("Yes, that is right!")
        print("It took you " + guessesTaken +  " guesses")
    if UserGuess == giveUp:
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
        randomNumber = str(randomNumber)
        print("Better luck next time.")
        print("You tried"+ guessesTaken +  " guesses")


    return
    print (main())

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: You have to ask the user again to input a number, if he did not guess correctly (inside the while loop)

Comment: BTW, fix your indent please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get more user input once you're inside the loop. Consider

```
UserGuess = None

while UserGuess != randomNumber:
    UserGuess = int(input("Take a guess" + "(The random number is: " + str(randomNumber) + "): "))
    guessesTaken += 1
    ....
```

As it stands, you're taking only the first guess. Then you're repeatedly reevaluating it. Since there's no chance for the user to change their guess, it loops infinitely.

---

Also, you'll want to change up the order of your if/elifs.

As it stands, the structure is

```
if guess (is too low)
if the guess (is not too low), and (is too high)
if the guess (is not too low), and (is not too high), and (is correct) or (is 'give up')
```

A quick way to get it working would be

```
if   UserGuess == randomNumber or UserGuess == giveUp:
    ...
elif UserGuess > randomNumber:
    ...
elif UserGuess < randomNumber:
    ....
```

Comment: I fixed that problem and now my program runs however when I enter -1 (which means i want to give up) it just says too low. any idea why?

Comment: @JaneDoe2 it's because if and elif statement blocks goes in order. Since -1 is lower than what you guessed it accept that statement and moves on, if you want you can move the third `elif` statement to the first one: `UserGuess == randomNumber or UserGuess == giveUp` make this your first if, and make your current first `if` to be an `elif`